# How to create new ndarray as same number of columns as other array but having zero rows

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

**let's say I have an array of shape (50, 784) as below**

```py
x_train = np.ones((50, 784), np.int16)
x_train.shape
```

**I want another array of shape (0, 784) which I will use to collect some rows of x_train matching some complex condition.**

**like shown in sudo code below**

```py
## sudo code
new_x_train = <initialize with array of shape (0,784)> 
for condition in conditions
    new_x_train = new_x_train.r_[new_x_train, elements_matching(condition, x_train)]
```

**I tried following code which gives array of shape (1,784)**

```py
np.empty_like(x_train[[0]]) # shape (1,784)
```

**Then I deleted the 1st row, which gives array of shape (0,784) which I wanted**

```py
np.delete(np.empty_like(x_train[[0]]), [0], axis=0) ## shape (0,784)
```

**Is there another clean way to do it?**

I know I can do as below but want multiple such array which leads to many such if-else block which I want to avoid

```
## sudo code
new_x_train = None
for condition in conditions
    if new_x_train == None:
       new_x_train = elements_matching(condition, x_train)
    else:
       new_x_train = new_x_train.r_[new_x_train, elements_matching(condition, x_train)]
```

Comment: `np.empty((0, x_train.shape[1]))` - but it would be a lot faster if you could pre-allocate the right number of rows from the start. Or else drop your arrays from the different conditions in a normal Python list and then call `np.concatenate` at the end.

Comment: Instead of creating an array with one row and deleting it, just do `np.empty((0,784))`. Note though that adding rows/concatenating iteratively is not recommended. Perhaps share what you're trying to do exactly and you might get some help in vectorizing this

Comment: Ya, I totally missed the "empty" function it does the work, thanks both for the answer. @yatu I want to create multiple arrays from x_train where each array will collect rows satisfying certain condition

Answer (score 0):

I would just do something like:

```
new_x_train = np.r_[[elements_matching(condition, x_train) for condition in conditions]]
```

i.e. just make a list of arrays and concatentate them at the end.